# Wiring a socket in the loft

Tags: electrical, wiring

Is it possible to change the existing light switch In the bedroom to a dual switch and then run the power cables to the loft and install a double socket up there?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the switch box?

Comment: Sure, it's [possible](https://youtu.be/nsJpTTIEySo?t=89) if you have the access etc... how exactly you do it will depend on how the existing wiring is run.  Honestly our format here calls for more in-depth questions with more detail... so maybe you can do some investigating and [edit] your question to add that detail.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the existing switch box please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.